# CSS class influencing elements not nested within the class

Tags: html, css

I have the following HTML in a page feature:

```
<div id="feature-detail">
    <div class="da1 d-active">
        <h1><span>Detail 1</span></h1>
        <p><span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</span></p>
        <a href="#"><span>Show how</span></a>       
    </div>
</div>
```

I then have further down the page:

```
<div id="page-submain" class="centred">
    <div id="left-widget" class="widget">
        <h1><span>Title</span></h1>
        <p><span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</span></p>
        <a href="#"><span>Read More</span></a>
    </div>
</div>
```

NOTE: Neither of the above parent `<div>` elements are nested within each other. Both have a parent of `<body>`.

When I run some tests on the CSS structure, I have noticed that this style rule:

```
.widget p,a,h2 {
    margin:3px 5px 3px 5px;
    padding:0;
}
```

Is influencing the `<a>` in `#feature-detail`. Why is this doing that when I've explicitly applied the style to the class 'widget'?

Not making a huge amount of sense to me at the moment, but it seems that IE, FF, Chrome and Opera are interpretting it exactly the same. Am I missing something here?

Thanks for taking a look!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you've written is equivalent to:

```
.widget p {
    margin:3px 5px 3px 5px;
    padding:0;
}
a {
    margin:3px 5px 3px 5px;
    padding:0;
}
h2 {
    margin:3px 5px 3px 5px;
    padding:0;
}
```

What you want is:

```
.widget p, .widget a, .widget h2 {
    margin:3px 5px 3px 5px;
    padding:0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The selector used in this:

```
.widget p,a,h2 {
    margin:3px 5px 3px 5px;
    padding:0;
}
```

matches "p elements that are a descendant of elements with the class widget", all `a` elements and all `h2` elements.

If you want the `a` rule to only apply to `a` elements that are a descendant of an element with the class `widget`, you need to specify that (and you'd have to do the same with `h2` if you want that to behave in a similar way):

```
.widget p, .widget a, h2
```

Comment: Thanks James, I'm aware of this. The issue is, the `a` element in `#feature-links` is not a descendant of class `widget`.

Comment: Apologies James, I understand what you wrote now having seen the below answers. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the comma delimiter means you have actually multiple selectors. So the selector `.widget p,a,h2` matches:

- All P's in `.widget`
- All A's, regardless
- All H2's, regardless.

Change it to:

```
.widget p, .widget a, .widget h2 {...
```

Comment: Thanks, I see what I was doing now. Must be more specific with my rules.

Answer (score 0):

The tags  and  are not nested within .widget class. I have re-formatted the css On [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/DSe7j/) . Have a look on it.